# Java drawimage() crops original image

Tags: java, 2d, platform

I started programming in Java and I wanted to make a little project, which is a platform 2d game with basic inputs.
I would like the game to scale its resolution  according to the player's monitor, but in order to do so I need to paint a resized version of the game's view.
The main problem is that in my game's model I am using absolute coordinates to place items in the game world  so I don't want my coordinates to change in the scaled version.
After some research I decided to scale my game using a BufferedImage and the drawImage() method.

Problems start when I try to scale my background from my model's coordinates to the player's screen , the background image is cropped, and I lose the bottom part of my background.

This is the part where i try to scale my image:

```
final private int modelX = 480;
final private int modelY = 560;

final private int screenX;
final private int screenY;

public class Board extends JPanel{

Board(){
    Dimension s = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    this.screenX = s.getWidth/4;
    this.screenY = s.getHeigth/2;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("background.png");

  //I create a new bufferedImage, the size of my game model.

    BufferedImage canvas = new BufferedImage(modelX,modelY,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics canvasGraphics = buffer.getGraphics();

 //I fill the whole canvas with my  scaled background picture

  canvasGraphics.drawImage(background.getImage(),0,0,canvas.getWidth,canvas.getHeight,null)
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
//Finally, I fill my screen  with my canvas
    g2d.drawImage(canvas,0,0,screenX,screenY,null);

}

}
```

Comment: How are you initializing/updating modelX, modelY, screenX, and screenY?

Comment: @mm8511 my bad, I should've explained before. ModelX and ModelY are what I am using in my model so I can't change those, I get the screenwidth and heigth according to the user's resolution